# Is file I/O to tmpfs better performing than redis?

Tags: file, unix, tmp

If /tmp is mounted with tmpfs, does this increase the speed of file I/O? Would file I/O to tmp in this way perform as well as something like redis?
I'm wondering about all resources, not just speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, increasing access speed (latency and throughput) is the idea of having `tmpfs`. Instead of flushing to hard disk all the time, the file system will try to keep all the content in RAM, which leads to very low latency compared to a normal disk-based file system. Obviously once you run out of RAM, it has to resort to using an on-disk swap file.

This blog post describes using `tmpfs` to improve the speed of serving websites, and goes into a lot of technical detail if you're interested: [30x Faster Cache and Site Speed with TMPFS](http://www.askapache.com/optimize/super-speed-secrets.html)